# How to take data from one side of a symbol

Tags: python, regex

I am working on making a calculator with python and need a way to detect what number is on each side of the operator sign. For example 3 - 61, I wish for it to detect 3 and 61 and put them into variables num1 and num2

I am currently using RegEx to find all the numbers, but this will even separate an number like 10 or 87 into 1 and 0 or 8 and 7.

This is what I currently have:

```
import re

var = input("Type equation:")

elif " - " in var:
    nums = str(re.findall(r'\d',var))
    nums2 = nums.replace("['", "")
    nums3 = nums2.replace("', '", "")
    Numbers = nums3.replace("']", "")
    num1, num2 = (int(i) for i in str(Numbers))
    answer = num1 - num2
    print(answer)
```

My expected results for a problem like 10 - 6 would be 4

My actual results are too many numbers error
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I know that is caused because my program can only do single numbers but I wish for it to be able to do more than single digit numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var = input("Type equation:")

if " - " in var:
    nums = var.split(' - ')
    num1, num2 = (int(i) for i in nums)
    answer = num1 - num2
    print(answer)
```

this would be a solution that works for the situation you've described. Note that I removed the `str()` part in the `num1, num2` part because split will give you back a list of values that it split. That putting the `str()` would concat them again and you'd be no further than before.

You were close to the solution with your attempt.

```
import re

var = input("Type equation:")

if " - " in var:
    nums = re.findall(r'\d+',var)
    num1, num2 = (int(i) for i in nums)
    answer = num1 - num2
    print(answer)
```

this one will work. You've overused the `str()` meaning, find all gave you a list back and with `str()` you told the interpreter to concat the list into a string again, which gave you the wird `[]` stuff. If you leave the `str()` away it should work, like i've described in the second code section.

Comment: @CharGamer gonna edit the post right now to add some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the input by using `var.split(" - ")`. This would return an array of strings. You could then just cast all the strings to ints and add or subtract them:

```py
# get all the numbers (only works for subtraction)
numbers = var.split(" - ")

result = 0
for number in numbers:
    # no error checking here; should be implemented
    result -= int(number)

print(result)
```

Keep in mind that you would also have to check for multiple signs e.g. `4 + 2 - 5`

Comment: how would I import the equation into there? would I do something like var.split("1 - 3")

Comment: just like you did it in your example: via input(). split only... well splits an already existing string into parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in subtraction between 2 numbers and it is formatted exactly like `X - X` then you can simply use `split` function to solve it:

```
var = input("Type equation:")
nums = var.split(" - ")
print(int(nums[0]) - int(nums[1]))
```

If you insist using regex you can solve it similarly like this:

```
var = input("Type equation:")
nums = re.findall(r'\d+',var) #\d+ means 1 or more digits
print(int(nums[0]) - int(nums[1]))
```